# using axios with reducer / context / provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using useEffect to make an api call to set initialState, then pass it to "todo" with useReducer

code here:

```
export function TodoProvider({children}){

  const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3001/home";

  const [initialState,setInitialState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(apiUrl)
    .then((response)=>{
        setInitialState(response.data.data);
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e))
  },[]);

  console.log(initialState);

  const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, initialState);


  return (
      <TodoContext.Provider value={todo}>
        <TodoDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
            {children}
        </TodoDispatchContext.Provider>
      </TodoContext.Provider>
    )
  }
```

but todo isn't getting the value of initialState, does anyone know what am i doing wrong here?

is it because useReducer() only gets the first time value from initialState? is there a different way to do it?

and in the inspector in chrome
that one console.log(initialState) prints these:
[image]
thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, There's a question, Why are you using context when you already have a global store. Redux already provides store to save data globally and access it. So need some more clearance pls.

Comment: @sharvilpandit hi thanks for helping. I'm only use Context and Reducer, not using Redux library in it. I have todolist with reducer and context providers to feed data to components. it worked fine when initialState was hardcoded. now  i try to provide the list from expressjs api instead using axios.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seem to be caused due to the initialState passed to useReducer staying as an empty array.

You can update the state and reducer declaration as:

```
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState(null);

  const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, initialState || []);
```

and conditionally render, as:

```
  if (initialState === null) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={todo}>
      <TodoDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </TodoDispatchContext.Provider>
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
```

Full code:

```
export function TodoProvider({ children }) {
  const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3001/home";

  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        setInitialState(response.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);


  const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, initialState || []);


  if (initialState === null) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={todo}>
      <TodoDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </TodoDispatchContext.Provider>
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi TK thanks for help. and show me initialState || [], that's cool. you right he issue is it's todo staying empty array. I tried your way to do it, it still won't feed value from initialState to todo. is it because useReducing only gets the first value from initialState?